# How to convert a JSON data into an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json

Hellow guys..!
I need your help on converting JSON data into an array in javascript. Here below are my codes;

```
    //---Variable----// 
    JsonData = [{"id":1,"Bus_RegNo":"T 784 DHJ","Name":"Bus1"}];

    BusArray = [];

    //---Converting JSON into an array--//
    StringfiedData = JSON.stringify(JsonData);

    BusArray = JSON.parse(StringfiedData); 

    alert(StringfiedData);
```

I tried to convert it but when alerting 'BusArray' am getting [object object], I need to get something like;

```
    {"1","T 784 DHJ","Bus1"}
```

please help;

Comment: Your `JsonData` is already an array. If it had quotes wrapping it it would be JSON (a string). `console.log(JsonData[0]);` to see.

Comment: The output you specify as `I need to get something like` is not a valid data structure - it is sort of a cross between an array and an object literal

Comment: `JsonData` is an array. It's not a JSON string. Your expected output is invalid. If you want to values of the first object inside the array, you need: `Object.values(JsonData[0])`.

Comment: Thank you guys, @Professor Abronsius, I actually needed to get a normal array which I can loop through it and get it's element values, so in the question above I should have to write  something like this ["1","T 784 DHJ","Bus1"] to mean a normal array.

Comment: Whatever format it is in you should be able to iterate over it in the way you need to. It is as-easy to iterate over object properties as it is array items - `Object.keys` and `Object.values` both yield iterable arrays

Comment: Thank you @ Professor Abronsius, I have managed to iterate on it now, using those object functions mentioned above "Object.keys and Object.values".